# Summarizing percentage by subgroups

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I don't know how to explain my problem, but I want to summarize the categories `distance` and get the percentage for each distance per month. In my table 1 week is 100% and now I want to calculate the same for the month but using the percentage from the weeks.
Something like sum(percent)/ amount of weeks in this month
This is what I have:

```
  year  month year_week distance object_remarks        weeksum percent
 1 2017  05    2017_21   15       ctenolabrus_rupestris       3  0.75  
 2 2017  05    2017_21   10       ctenolabrus_rupestris       1  0.25  
 3 2017  05    2017_22   5        ctenolabrus_rupestris       5  0.833 
 4 2017  05    2017_22   0        ctenolabrus_rupestris       1  0.167
 5 2017  06    2017_22   0        ctenolabrus_rupestris       9  1   
 6 2017  06    2017_23   20       ctenolabrus_rupestris       6  0.545 
 7 2017  06    2017_23   0        ctenolabrus_rupestris       5  0.455
```

I want to have an output like this:

```
  year  month  distance object_remarks        weeksum percent percent_month
 1 2017  05    15       ctenolabrus_rupestris       3  0.75           0.375
 2 2017  05    10       ctenolabrus_rupestris       1  0.25          0.1225
 3 2017  05    5        ctenolabrus_rupestris       5  0.833         0.4165 
 4 2017  05    0        ctenolabrus_rupestris       1  0.167         0.0835

 5 2017  06    0        ctenolabrus_rupestris       14 1.455         0.7275
 6 2017  06    20       ctenolabrus_rupestris       6  0.545         0.2775
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `group_by()` twice.

```
df %>%
  select(-year_week) %>%
  group_by(month, distance) %>%
  mutate(percent = sum(percent), weeksum = sum(weeksum)) %>%
  distinct %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  mutate(percent_month = percent/sum(percent))

# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Groups:   month [2]
#    year month distance object_remarks        weeksum percent percent_month
#   <int> <int>    <int> <chr>                   <int>   <dbl>         <dbl>
# 1  2017     5       15 ctenolabrus_rupestris       3   0.75         0.375 
# 2  2017     5       10 ctenolabrus_rupestris       1   0.25         0.125 
# 3  2017     5        5 ctenolabrus_rupestris       5   0.833        0.416 
# 4  2017     5        0 ctenolabrus_rupestris       1   0.167        0.0835
# 5  2017     6        0 ctenolabrus_rupestris      14   1.46         0.728 
# 6  2017     6       20 ctenolabrus_rupestris       6   0.545        0.272
```

Comment: @EmelySiewert it's my fault. `distinct` should be put in the middle of code. I had edit it.